# iTunes Connect review process for an application that depends on MAC Address

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

In my work, we have an application ready and we want to put it into the App Store. The application is usable only with clients that are pre-registered to our service. We recognize them by their device's MAC Address (we don't use e-mails and passwords).

So, the problem is: Since in order to test the application you are required to have your device pre-registered using its MAC Address, how can Apple test it since we don't have their device's MAC Address pre-registered?

Therefore the actual question: Is there any way to tell apple to contact us for pre-registering their test device prior to actually testing the application?

PS. I know that there is the "developer notes" field in iTunesConnect when you submit the binary, but is that the only way of contacting the App Review Team for such reasons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will respond my own question, since I have stumbled across this lately.

Short answer: Can't be done. We have developed a workaround that will allow anyone with a specific build to login in to a test account even if he is unregistered and his MAC address is not recognised. So, the old versions remain intact, and the new version waiting to be accepted is actually a wildcard allowing anyone to test it, in this case, Apple.

It's the only way.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue with an application that required accounts registered from another place. Apple contacted me and asked to provide a test account information in the meta data section at iTunes Connect. You can provide a detailed explanation there and a sample account (the developer notes you mentioned).

Comment: The problem is that creating a test account needs a MAC address (we expect our clients to contact us in person in order to open an account to our service). However, your post was helpful indeed.